# Ziegler–Nichols method of PID auto tuning

Tags: microcontroller, control-system, microchip, pid-controller, tuning

I am working on a problem where I need to implement **auto tuning PID** control using **Ziegler–Nichols method**. Basically I want to control temperature using it.
The PID has to be implemented with the Microchip PIC 18F microcontroller.

However, I have no knowledge of the system's transfer function. So, how can I implement it?

Also, I would appreciate any good docs to read about it.
I had read about Ziegler–Nichols method. The problem I encountered is to find the ultimate gain and ultimate period.

We need to get Kp such that the system is oscillatory for step input. but as a temperature controller I am unable to implement that in a dynamic system.

What can be the possible solution?

Comment: What system are you going to control? Some heating element? What are the sources of "disturbances"? Some cold? Usually you need to measure the time constant of system (open loop) as first. I recommend during constant conditions (no disturbances presented). Or measure this disturbances and correct the measured time-const.

Comment: @Michal yes, the system is a heating element.

Comment: One issue is that if i measure time conatant of open loop system then won't the PID coefficients be fixed. but i need an auto-tuning system which sets PID acc. to the system requirements. Can anyone help me.